# ZSH is not showing current path's .deb files

Tags: apt, deb, zsh

I am trying to install clapper from the .deb file in my Ubuntu 20.04. Last night I installed and configured ZSH for the first time. I think I made some errors during config, as the following happens.

With apt / aptitude, shows **no files found**. but with dpkg, it installs the Debian file.

apt/aptitude shows following after pressing tab after "c". where current path has only 1 file. (NB - clapper_xyz.deb is not among these 1640 lines)

`aptitude install c`<kbd>Tab</kbd>
`zsh: do you wish to see all 1640 possibilities (1640 lines)?`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the complete list of steps that you followed to try and install the software via the .deb? This will make it much easier to offer specific answers 

Comment: I have already done an edit, does this help?

Comment: Everywhere I am looking right now is basically showing that `aptitude` cannot install a `.deb` file from the command line.  It appears to only have the ability to install an app from a PPA that is setup on the system.  I have seen out there people using `dpkg -i clapper_xyz.deb` then running `aptitude install clapper_xyz` that will then download and install the dependencies needed.  But by this point, it is easier just to do `sudo apt install ./clapper_xyz.deb` that will automatically install dependencies needed.

Comment: The tab completion for `aptitude` is designed to complete package names from whatever repositories are added, not package files from the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be simpler to refer to the current directory, so that the command completion has something specific to work on instead of attempting to complete every possibility that starts with `c`. Add in `./` before the `c`:

`aptitude install ./c`<kbd>TAB</kbd>

Comment: Tried with both absolute and relative path, but aptitude simply ignoring any user given path/file.